# How to map single object of type x to array of object of type y using automapper

Tags: arrays, mapping, automapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.defs, opt => opt.MapFrom(origin => origin.abc));
```

where defs is array of Def (Def[])

how to map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.defs, opt => opt.MapFrom(origin => new[]{ origin.abc }));
```

destination property is array of Def and so the source requries array of something, that's how automapper understands...

this works!!!

Comment: You can also use a custom resolver, if you want to put this logic in a separate, reusable class.