# Automapper with nested child objects

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public class Domain {
    public string a;
    public string b
    public string c;
    public string d;
}

public class Child {
    public string b;
    public string c;
    public string d;
}

public class ParentDto {
    public string a;
    public Child[] children;
}
```

1. How to map Domain to ParentDto?

Domain contains multiple records from DB ie Map Multiple source objects to one destination object that contains an Array of objects.

Comment: Pls refer to http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html and use properties, not fields.

Comment: Fields work too.

Comment: Hi Amo,
That link shows direct 1 to 1 mapping...this is many to 1 mapping. Parent will have only 1 object. I have googled for 4 days & have not figured out how to do this mapping?

Thanks

Comment: I tried these 2 solutions but it didnt work...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191768/how-to-map-single-object-of-type-x-to-array-of-object-of-type-y-using-automapper

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735562/how-to-map-single-object-properties-to-array-of-object-in-complex-type-using-aut

Comment: gave up automapper route...did it quite easily using Linq..    

var results = DB.GetDomain()  
results.children = results.Select(src => new Child{ b = src.b, c= src.c, d= src.d}).ToArray<Child>();